# How do I configure a Netgear FVS336g for use with Amazon VPC?

Tags: networking, router, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, ipsec

I think it should be possible to create an IPSec tunnel between a Netgear FVS336Gv2 firewall/router and AWS VPC however, I've been unable after several tries. How do I setup a connection for a Amazon VPC?

Comment: Yes, it does work. I have created a successful connection with this device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

AWS has just dropped the requirement to establish [Border Gateway Protocol (BGP)](http://www.netgear.co.uk/business/products/security/wired-VPN-firewalls/FVS336G.aspx) peerings in order to use the built in VPN connectivity to an [Amazon Virtual Private Cloud (VPC)](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonVPC/latest/NetworkAdminGuide/Introduction.html#DevicesTested), see [Amazon VPC - Additional VPN Features](http://aws.amazon.com/vpc/):

> You can now create Hardware VPN connections to your VPC using static
>   routing. This means that you can **establish connectivity using VPN
>   devices that do not support BGP** such as Cisco ASA and **Microsoft
>   Windows Server 2008 R2**. You can also use  **Linux** to establish a
>   Hardware VPN connection to your VPC. **In fact, any IPSec VPN
>   implementation should work**. *[emphasis mine]*

The outlined reason for this change specifically highlights BGP as a previous barrier to adoption of this otherwise very appealing VPN connectivity to a VPC:

> First, BGP can be difficult to set up and to manage, [...]. Second, some firewalls and entry-level
>   routers support IPSec but not BGP. These devices are very popular in
>   corporate branch offices. As I mentioned above, this change
>   dramatically increases the number of VPN devices that can be used to
>   connect to a VPC. [...]

I couldn't agree more - consequently you might be able to establish an IPSec tunnel between your Netgear FVS336Gv2 firewall/router and an AWS VPC now:

> We have tested the static routing "No BGP" option 
>   with devices from Cisco, Juniper, Yamaha, **Netgear**, and Microsoft.  *[emphasis mine]*

---

### Initial Answer

I doubt that the [Netgear FVS336Gv2](http://www.netgear.co.uk/business/products/security/wired-VPN-firewalls/FVS336G.aspx) will work with the [Amazon Virtual Private Cloud (VPC)](http://aws.amazon.com/vpc/), insofar it is neither mentioned in [Customer Gateway Devices We've Tested](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonVPC/latest/NetworkAdminGuide/Introduction.html#DevicesTested), nor completely fulfills the respective [Requirements for Your Customer Gateway](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonVPC/latest/NetworkAdminGuide/Introduction.html#CGRequirements) - in particular, Amazon VPC requires support for establishing [Border Gateway Protocol (BGP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Border_Gateway_Protocol) peerings:

> BGP is used to exchange routes between the customer gateway and
>   virtual private gateway. All BGP traffic is encrypted and transmitted
>   via the IPsec Security Association. BGP is required for both gateways
>   to exchange the IP prefixes reachable via the IPsec SA.

Unfortunately, BGP is not implemented in many consumer-level VPN devices, thus requires respective professional hardware or software VPN appliances - the Netgear FVS336Gv2 doesn't seem to be an exception here, at least BGP isn't listed in the product specification (see tab *Product Specs* on its [product page](http://www.netgear.co.uk/business/products/security/wired-VPN-firewalls/FVS336G.aspx)).

Comment: This answer is great at telling us that it's possible, but not how.  Any way to maybe clean this up and give a quick synopsis on how to do this?